# How do I include a matplotlib Figure object as subplot?

Tags: matplotlib

How can I use a matplotlib Figure object as a subplot?  Specifically, I have a function that creates a matplotlib Figure object, and I would like to include this as a subplot in another Figure.

In short, here's stripped-down pseudocode for what I've tried:

```
    fig1 = plt.figure(1, facecolor='white')
    figa = mySeparatePlottingFunc(...)
    figb = mySeparatePlottingFunc(...)
    figc = mySeparatePlottingFunc(...)
    figd = mySeparatePlottingFunc(...)
    fig1.add_subplot(411, figure=figa)
    fig1.add_subplot(412, figure=figb)
    fig1.add_subplot(413, figure=figc)
    fig1.add_subplot(414, figure=figd)
    fig1.show()
```

Sadly, however, this fails.  I know for a fact the individual plots returned from the function invocations are viable--I did a figa.show(),...,figd.show() to confirm that they are OK.  What I get for the final line in the above code block--fig1.show()--is 
a collection of four empty plots that have frames and x- and y- tickmarks/labels.

I've done quite a bit of googling around, and experimented extensively, but it's clear that I've missed something that is either really subtle, or embarrassingly obvious (I'll be happy for it to be the latter as long as I can get un-stuck).

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't put a `figure` in a `figure`.

You should modify your plotting functions to take `axes` objects as an argument.

I am also unclear why the kwarg `figure` is there, I think it is an artifact of the way that inheritance works, the way that the documentation is auto-generated, and the way some of the getter/setter work is automated.  If you note, it says `figure` is undocumented in the `Figure` documentation, so it might not do what you want;).  If you dig down a bit, what that kwarg really controls is the figure that the created axes is attached too, which is not what you want.

In general, moving existing axes/artists between figures is not easy, there are too many bits of internal plumbing that need to be re-connected.  I *think* it can be done, but will involving touching the internals and there is no guarantee that it will work with future versions or that you will get warning if the internals change in a way that will break it.

You need to your plotting functions to take an `Axes` object as argument.  You can use a pattern like:

```
def myPlotting(..., ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        # your existing figure generating code
        ax = gca()
```

so if you pass in an `Axes` object it gets drawn to (the new functionality you need), but if you don't all of your old code will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell.  Sadly, I remain a bit confused.  Why does the matplotlib API for subplot seem to offer a matplotlib Figure instance as an argument?  Rather than having my function return a matplotlib Figure instance, I can get back a matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object.  Is that something I can use to proceed, and if so, how would I modify my example code block to use it?  Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks for the further advice @tcaswell.  I've started up the path this way, but am putting it aside for the moment.  You're right that this is a surprisingly messy process.  For now, I may have to resign myself to generating the individual plots (which works just fine), saving them to individual files, and stitching them together in a single plot with some other tool (probably just use LaTeX's figure/subfigure environment).

Comment: Using the @tacaswell's solution is good enough. It just needs a different design and planning for the layout of the figures with subplots and an understanding of the resulted axes' array structure, then the ax element as "anchor" to plot and attach the sub-plots to the ax elements.